# Disprove that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}_{>0},$ there exists $y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $y<n \in \mathbb{N}, n<x$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

So i have been asked to prove this statement in one of my courses.

In class we learned that if we want to disprove for-all statement we should prove there-exist statement, and if we want to disprove there-exist statements we should prove for-all statement.

So to begin my disprove of the statement I started by choosing x = 1/2 and let y be a real number.

But my question is how to use **n**?

should I prove there-exist statement, because like I said above - when we want to disprove for-all statement we should prove there-exist statement, and by so to choose n to be a specific (natural) number.

or should I let n be a natural number?

I know it may seem a basic question, but I really can't determine **why** is one of the above correct, and i would like to know in general how to prove this kind of statements.

Comment: It's hard to help without knowing what you know about $\mathbb R$.  Do you know that, given any real number $z$, there exists  a natural number $N$ with $N>z$?  If so, then for any given $y$, take $z=\max (x,y)$.

Comment: I think I changed your title to something else by accident because it doesn't make much sense. Not to me anyway. Are you given an integer $n$?

Comment: I should disprove that if x is real and positive number, there exist y real number such that for all N<n integer: n < x.
(Not formally we can take x = 1/2 and then n must be greater than x because n is an integer).. 
so my question is -  should i take n to be a specific number - for example 1? or should i say that for all n: n > 1/2 ...

Comment: Think about what the statement means and why it should seem to be utterly absurd.  Then try to put you argument into a formal proof.  This is saying that for all $x$ there is a number $y$ so that for all natural numbers larger than $y$, those natural numbers must be smaller than $x$.  That's clearly nonsense as the natural numbers can be as large as we like and can certainly be larger than both $x$ and $y$.  Now make that into a formal argument.